# Pytorch: Mask dilation / extension

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, pytorch

I wonder how to extend / dilate binary mask in pytorch? i.e. it should be something like [cv2.dilate](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=dilate#dilate) from opencv.

Comment: do you need gradients to propagate through this op?

Answer (score 2):

For rectangular neighborhoods, dilation is the same as max pooling.
See [`nn.MaxPool2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxPool2d.html#torch.nn.MaxPool2d) for implementation details.